# Why is $\tan x$ not a continuous function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, continuity

My textbook defines a continuous function as follows:

The function $f(x)$ is continuous if, for all $a$ in its domain, $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)$ exists and is equal to $f(a)$.

However, when I apply this to $f(x)=\tan x$, it seems to show that $\tan x$ is continuous, because:

For all $a$ in the domain of $\tan x$ (i.e. all real numbers except $\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}, n\in \mathbb{Z}$), we have that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \tan x$ exists and is equal to $\tan a$ (this can be easily seen from the graph of $\tan x$).

So it appears that $\tan x$ is continuous. However, I already know that it isn't continuous at $x=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}$. Does this still mean it is continuous because it agrees with the definition? I'm not sure what to do now.

Edit: Really what I meant to ask is the following:

Here is the wording in the book: "A function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$, if $f(a)$ is defined and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)$ is defined and is equal to $f(a)$. A continuous function satisfies this condition for all values of $a$ in its domain, so the graph of a continuous function is unbroken."

Question: I'm assuming the book's definition is wrong? Because the last sentence seems to imply that $\tan x$ is continuous (which is what had me confused).

Comment: The tangent function *is* continuous on its domain; it isn’t a continuous function on $\Bbb R$ simply because it isn’t defined on all of $\Bbb R$ (and moreover, the discontinuities aren’t even removable).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I see, that makes perfect sense and seems to answer my question. Why did you only put it as a comment?

Comment: Probably because he was not able to answer the question as stated in the title ("Why is $\tan x$ not a continuous function?", when it is continuous in its domain). You might wan't to change the title to "Why is $\tan x$ not defined in the entire domain $\mathbb{R}$?".

Comment: @john: I was rushing off to do something else and wasn’t sure that it would completely answer your question or when I’d be back.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Here is the wording in the book: "A function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$, if $f(a)$ is defined and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)$ is defined and is equal to $f(a)$. A continuous function satisfies this condition for all values of $a$ in its domain, so the graph of a continuous function is unbroken." So I'm assuming the book's definition is wrong? Because the last sentence seems to imply that $\tan x$ is continuous (which is what had me confused). Thanks by the way.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I'm not sure whether or not this is possible, but you might want to edit the one existing answer, and change the user who posted it to yourself.

Comment: @john: Yes, by that definition $\tan x$ is continuous, and the statement about the graph is false: the graph is unbroken if the domain is ‘unbroken’ (i.e., is an interval, a ray, or the whole line). I have no quarrel with the book’s definition of continuity itself.

Comment: @barakmanos: I wasn't sure how to word it because of my book's definition. The book's definition seems to imply that $\tan x$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, however I already know why it isn't continuous in $\mathbb{R}$. If someone can confirm that the book's definition is wrong, I will greatly appreciate it. I have added this more refined question as an edit, which I hope is ok.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Ok that's great, I knew there was something wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @johncastro Continuity has to be defined on a domain (just like functions do). It is technically incomplete to say a function is continuous without qualifying the statement with a domain. Generally when you sometimes read that a function is continuous, it implicitly means the function is continuous on its domain.

Comment: You may be interested in this question on [the continuity of the reciprocal function](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/4165/is-the-reciprocal-function-continuous); there issues are basically the same.

Answer (score 8):

The following is a copy-paste of @[Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12042/brian-m-scott)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070973/why-is-tan-x-not-a-continuous-function#comment4252563_2070973):

> The tangent function *is* continuous on its domain; it isn’t a continuous function on $\Bbb R$ simply because it isn’t defined on all of $\Bbb R$ (and moreover, the discontinuities aren’t even removable)

Comment: I just duplicated the answer @TripleARaz posted because I'm tired of the edit war.

Answer (score 0):

In complex analysis, tangent function can be expressed as an infinite sum of partial fractions about the poles:

$$\tan z=
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2z}{\left( k+\frac{1}{2} \right)^2 \pi^2-z^2}$$

which is continuous for any region without the poles.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind a short answer. $ \tan.. = \sin../\cos.. $. Sin is continuous but $\cos$ is in the denominator, creating infinities periodically as quotients.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of tangent function is the set
$$ \operatorname{im}^{-1} \tan = \bigcup_{j=-\infty}^\infty \left]\pi j - \frac\pi 2,\pi j + \frac\pi 2\right[
$$
Evidently $\tan$ is continuous on this set.

Discussing about the continuity of $\tan$ at the points $\pi/2 + \pi j$ is absurd, since $\tan$ is not defined on these points. (It is not defined as $\infty$ either!)

$\tan$ can be continuously extended to $\mathbb{R}$ by enlarging its image to the one-point compactification $\mathbb{R}^*$ of $\mathbb{R}$, and define
$$ \tan \left( \pi j + \frac{\pi}{2} \right) = \infty, \qquad j \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
Then $\tan:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^*$ is continuous.